# Magento 2 products list API - How to list configurable products, which has simple products with a specific custom attribute value

Tags: list, api, product, magento2

In my magento 2 site, I have configurable products and simple products. On product listing page, I am listing only configurable products using this API call -

```
GET V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=configurable
```

products has a custom attribute cb_color, which is applied to simple products only.

How to list configurable products, which has simple products with a specific cb_color custom attribute value?

This API call returns empty result -

```
GET V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=type_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=configurable&

searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=cb_color
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=326
```

because configurable does not have custom attribute cb_color

Comment: Did you get any solution regarding the same ?

Comment: Hi Siju, Zed
Did you find any solution for this?